# How do you find the sum of a series going from negative infinity to -1?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is :  $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} 2^n z^{-n}$

I found that you can invert the series to this: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} z^{k}$

I want to know how it is possible and some explanation.

Comment: This sum is a limit. Now use the delta epsilon formulation to observe for yourself that both limits are the same. You won't have to handle infinity this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going from $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} 2^n z^{-n}$ to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} z^{k}$ is just a substitution.

Start with $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} 2^n z^{-n}$.

Let $k = -n$.  Then when $n = -\infty$, we have $k = -n = -(-\infty) = +\infty$.  Also, when $n = -1$, we have $k=-n = -(-1) = 1$.  So the limits of the new sum in terms of $k$ are $1$ and $\infty$.

But why did the limits change position?  That is, why is the "infinity" limit on the bottom for the $n$ sum but the corresponding "infinity" limit is on the top for the $k$ sum?  Addition is commutative, so it doesn't matter what order we add things in, and it's custom to put the smaller sum limit on the bottom of the $\sum$.  This is why we say $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$ instead of $\sum_{k=\infty}^1$.  Actually, the notation $\sum_{k=\infty}^1$ doesn't have a universally agreed upon interpretation if I recall correctly.  But in this context we know it's safe to say $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$ because it came from us rewriting the existing sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}$.

So what about the $2^nz^{-n}$?  Recall that we said $k = -n$.  So then $n = -k$.  This means $2^n = 2^{-k}$ and $z^{-n} = z^{-(-k)} = z^k$.  Therefore $2^nz^{-n} = 2^{-k}z^k$ and all together we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} z^{k}$.

Comment: Despite addition bring commutative, the order can matter in an infinite sum.  It might be conditionally but not absolutely convergent.

Answer (score -2):

An infinite series can written as a infinite sequence of finite sums.

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}2^nz^{-n}=\lim_{N\to -\infty}S_N=\sum_{n=N}^{-1}2^nz^{-n}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}z^n=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N2^{-n}z^n$$

The infinite series converges if the infinite sequence converges (and they will have the same limit).

If we write these sequences out we have

$$(S_N)_{N=-\infty}^{-1}=\sum_{n=-1}^{-1}2^nz^{-n},\enspace \sum_{n=-2}^{-1}2^nz^{-n},...$$

$$(S_N)_{N=1}^{\infty}=\sum_{n=1}^{1}2^{-n}z^n,\enspace \sum_{n=1}^{2}2^{-n}z^{n},...$$

You should notice that the corresponding terms in each sequence are equal. You don't need to substitute, you can simply write them out. Hence, the sequences, and consequently the series, are equivalent.

Comment: I'd love feedback on why this was downvoted